# Reading nodes from multiple html and storing result as a vector

Tags: r, for-loop, web-scraping

I have a list of locally saved html files. I want to extract multiple nodes from each html and save the results in a vector. Afterwards, I would like to combine them in a dataframe. Now, I have a piece of code for 1 node, which works (see below), but it seems quite long and inefficient if I apply it for ~ 20 variables. Also, something really strange with the saving to vector (XXX_name) it starts with the last observation and then continues with the first, second, .... Do you have any suggestions for simplifying the code/ making it more efficient?

```
# Extracts name variable and stores in a vector 
XXX_name <- c()
for (i in 1:216) { 
  XXX_name <- c(XXX_name, name)
  mydata <- read_html(files[i], encoding = "latin-1") 
  reads_name <- html_nodes(mydata, 'h1') 
  name <- html_text(reads_name) 
  #print(i) 
  #print(name) 
}
```

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can put the workings inside a function then apply that function to each of your variables with `map`

First, create the function:

```
read_names <- function(var, node) {

  mydata <- read_html(files[var], encoding = "latin-1") 
  reads_name <- html_nodes(mydata, node) 
  name <- html_text(reads_name) 
}
```

Then we create a df with all possible combinations of inputs and apply the function to that

```
library(tidyverse)

inputs <- crossing(var = 1:216, node = vector_of_nodes) 

output <- map2(inputs$var, inputs$node, read_names)
```

Comment: :@Shinobi_Atobe: Thanks! Would I not have to change the function everytime because I want to extract different nodes? In this case the node is 'h1' but for the next extraction this would have to change to reading a different node.